# My connection using Server-Sent Events (and Javascript/PHP) keeps dropping immediately

Tags: php, javascript, server-sent-events

Yesterday I dived into Server-Sent events, as they were a great way to create a newsfeed for an online game I'm creating. I had a working script that could subscribe to my feed, and a script that could pull the newsfeed from the MySql database within minutes, but for some reason it drops the connection every time... (and reconnects every 3 seconds, making it nothing better than just using AJAX with certain time intervals for example)

The javascript I'm using:

```
var source = new EventSource('http://theobg.itselementary.site50.net/gamefeed.php');
source.onmessage = function(e) {
    $("#gamefeed").html(e.data);
}
```

The PHP I'm using:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Connection: keep-alive');

function sendMsg($id, $msg) {
  echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
  echo "data: $msg" . PHP_EOL;
  echo PHP_EOL;
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}

//The file for connecting to my database here...
$gameid = 1;

$serverTime = time();
//Some mysql query to get the gamefeed from the database here..., gamefeed is structured like this: NEWS&OTHERNEWS&OLDERNEWS&EVENOLDERNEWS

sendMsg($serverTime, $gamefeed);

?>
```

I've looked all over the internet, but everything seems to work fine with me, except for the connection not being 'kept alive', and I have no clue as to why that is...can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance,
Dalionzo

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the data and send it using a loop.

```
<?php
while(true){
    //check for updates here
    if($updates){
        sendMsg($id,$data);
    }
    sleep(1);//loosen it up
}
```

Also, for easier coding you can try my php library for Server-sent Events. [Here](https://github.com/licson0729/libSSE-php)

Comment: Thanks for replying, but all that does is send infinite updates to my main page, causing it to crash; am I completely missing the point here? Or do I still need to figure out and add my own code for checking whether data has changed?

Comment: You need to add a sleep call to loosen it up.

Comment: I'm posted a new logic, check it.